# Python name 'os' is not defined even though it is explicitly imported

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module called `imtools.py` that contains the following function:

```
import os 

def get_imlist(path):
    return[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.jpg')]
```

When I attempt to call the function `get_imlist` from the console using `import imtools` and `imtools.get_imlist(path)`, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\PycharmProjects\first\imtools.py", line 5, in get_imlist
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

I'm new at Python and I must be missing something simple here, but cannot figure this out.  If I define the function at the console it works fine.  The specific history of this module script is as follows:  initially it was written without the `import os` statement, then after seeing the error above the `import os` statement was added to the script and it was re-saved.  The same console session was used to run the script before and after saving.

Comment: Are you sure you're importing this exact code (and not, for example, some older version without `import os`)? The line numbers don't match up between the source code and the exception message.

Comment: Yeah, what @NPE said. If you edit the file `imtools.py` you need to `reload(imtools)` at the console.

Comment: There's no issue with the code shown here.

Comment: Instead of closing or holding as off-topic, why not edit the question to include the detail about importing, fixing an error, then re-importing? If that ends up being a duplicate, mark as duplicate, not close/hold as not-reproducible. In other words, this is perfectly reproducible and a very good and on-topic question -- the OP just did not yet even know this could possibly be the error in Python, and thus couldn't have been expected to give all the details needed to reproduce it on the first try of asking the question.

Answer (score 20):

Based on small hints, I'm going to guess that your code didn't originally have the `import os` line in it but you corrected this in the source and re-imported the file.

The problem is that Python caches modules. If you `import` more than once, each time you get back the same module - it isn't re-read. The mistake you had when you did the first import will persist.

To re-import the `imtools.py` file after editing, you must use `reload(imtools)`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  I was under the impression that every time I saved a script in my editor that it would take care of all the variables loaded in the console.  I think just a cursory familiarity with an editor such as PyCharm leads one to this type of thinking, or at least it did in my case.  Thanks.

Comment: It is usually better to re-run the script as even reload (demoted to the inspect module in 3.x) will not dependably do what one wants (which is why it is no longer a builtin).

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I was aware there were edge cases where `reload` isn't 100% reliable, but since I have yet to run into one I've never investigated too far. How do you "re-run the script"?

Comment: @MarkRansom If one reloads a module with a class definition (perhaps the most common case and hardly an 'edge case'), existing instances remain instances of the old version of the class.  If one does `from mod import Class`, then `reload(mod)` will leave `Class` bound to the old version.  And so on.  Beginners easily trip over these facts.  Hiding reload in `imp`, now `importlib` (not `inspect`) was an alternative to deleting it completely.  ...  One re-runs a script the same way one ran it in the first place.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I run a script with `import`, but that doesn't work once the module is cached. If `reload` is taken away what is the alternative? And what alternative doesn't have the same problems that `reload` does?

Comment: @MarkRansom (1) Ah, terminology conflict.  To me, and many others, a python 'script' is a .py file run as the main module (and not cached).  In an Idle editor, F5 runs the file -- normally in a fresh process -- as if it were the main module.  (2)  But suppose one does a plain `import mymod` (and not some `as` or `from` variant`) in a shell, interacts with `mymod`, sees a deficiency, and edits and saves `mymod.py`.  If one has done the plain import and knows to delete or replace class instances, then reload can work.

Comment: @MarkRansom (3)  But in the Idle shell, it is easier and safer to just restart the shell and repeat `import mymod` (possibly via the history mechanism.  (With the console interpreter, one would have to quit and restart.)  I would advise this to any beginner. (4) When I edit an idlelib .py file and want to test it as part of Idle (rather than in isolation), I have to start a new instance of Idle to start fresh with the new version.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy my usual way of working is to edit the code in a window, then import or reload it and run some tests interactively from the Idle shell. Shutting down the shell each time would be a productivity killer for lots of different reasons. I know instinctively what objects get out of synch by a reload so it's never been a problem for me, but I can see where my advice might be dangerous for someone less experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem is with me I am also trying to follow the book of Programming Computer Vision with Python by Jan Erik Solem" [http://programmingcomputervision.com/]. I tried to explore on internet to see the problem but I did not find any valuable solution but I have solved this problem by my own effort.

First you just need to place the 'imtools.py' into the parent folder of where your Python is installed like C:\Python so place the file into that destination and type the following command:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
from imtools import *
```

Instead of typing the code with imtools.get_imlist() you just to remove the imtools from the code like:

```
get_imlist()
```

This may solve your problem as I had found my solution by the same technique I used.