# python flask app environment variables - OS is not defined

Tags: python, flask, operating-system, environment-variables

I have a python flask application. Inside it I am using a google maps API key to have an interactive map. I am attempting to replace my hardcoded API key (I know this is bad) with an environment variable. I am using the os module. Specifically, the os.environ.get() method, to retrieve my environment variable. In my attempts to make it work I am getting the following error in Chrome developer console:

```
(index):47 Uncaught ReferenceError: os is not defined
at (index):47
```

In my main module in the app, I have clearly imported the os module and imported the variable into my 'home' page view:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

import key as k          
import database as db    
import weather_forecast as wf
import os                             #####I am importing the os module!


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', 
                           key=k.api_key(), 
                           sites=db.create_site_list(),
                           api_key=os.environ.get('GOOGLE_MAPS_JS_API_KEY'))  ###my environment variable!
```

Why is 'os' not defined?

Comment: are you able to access `os` in other parts of the program? As in not in a flask method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python name 'os' is not defined even though it is explicitly imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747288/python-name-os-is-not-defined-even-though-it-is-explicitly-imported)

Comment: you are missing `import os`

Comment: Can you show the actual code where you're getting an error?

Comment: @adamgy this helped a lot thanks.